# how to connect keyboard enter button with imageview

Tags: android

I want to implement keyboard enter button listener in my imageview so when user click on keyboard enter button  imageview listener calll when user clickon enter button on keyboard this button click how I implement keyboard listener with my imageview?

in my code what ever text user enter on edittext when click on imageview its go to other acvitity with parameter i want this effect also perform when user click onkeyboard enter button

```
 editText2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2);
  ImageView imageView1 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);








       imageView1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

            mode="search";
            Intent iMenuList = new Intent(HomeMenu.this,  
                          SecondStep.class);

              Serachvalue=editText2.getText().toString();
            iMenuList.putExtra("Serachvalue", Serachvalue);



                startActivity(iMenuList);

            }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    imageView1 .setOnKeyListener(new OnKeyListener() 
    {

        @Override
        public boolean onKey(View arg0, int keyCode, KeyEvent arg2) 
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            if(keyCode==66)
            {
                //Do something
            }
            return false;
        }
    });
```

Try this may help you

Comment: what is key==66?? i want to click on enter button of keyboard

Comment: i want give usewr both choice either clickon imageview in application or click on enter button on keyboard both perform same action

Comment: keycode 66 is constant for enter button from keyboard and you have already added onClick listener for imageview right.so I just added code for Enter button .